# Custom post type not displaying content from single-{custom post type} page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, single

I am trying to create a custom post type with taxonomy and a shortcode for my custom search in a plugin.When I activate my plugin I see my CPT and taxonomy on dashboard. But when I publish the post I do not see the data in form of the single-{CPT}.php page I created. Instead, it displays list of all posts from my CPT. The relevent files are as below.

index.php (my plugin page)

```
function register_vfic_post_type() {        

    /* ----Begin Code to include Custom Post Types and its Taxonomies----- */

        register_post_type('vfic_publications', array(  'label' => 'VFIC Publications','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','revisions','author','page-attributes',),'labels' => array (
          'name' => 'VFIC Publications',
          'singular_name' => '',
          'menu_name' => 'VFIC Publications',
          'add_new' => 'Add VFIC Publications',
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New VFIC Publications',
          'edit' => 'Edit',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit VFIC Publications',
          'new_item' => 'New VFIC Publications',
          'view' => 'View VFIC Publications',
          'view_item' => 'View VFIC Publications',
          'search_items' => 'Search VFIC Publications',
          'not_found' => 'No VFIC Publications Found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No VFIC Publications Found in Trash',
          'parent' => 'Parent VFIC Publications',
        ),) );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_vfic_post_type' );

    register_taxonomy('Year',array (
        0 => 'vfic_publications',
        ),array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Year','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => false,'singular_label' => 'Year') );

    register_taxonomy('PubsAuthor',array (
        0 => 'vfic_publications',
        ),array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'PubsAuthor','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => false,'singular_label' => 'PubsAuthor') ); 

    register_taxonomy('Journal',array (
        0 => 'vfic_publications',
        ),array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Journal','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => false,'singular_label' => 'Journal') );

    register_taxonomy('nts',array (
        0 => 'vfic_publications',
        ),array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Non-Technical Summary','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => false,'singular_label' => 'nts') );

    function vfic_ctg_rewrite_flush() {
        register_vfic_post_type();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'vfic_ctg_rewrite_flush' );

/* ----END Code to include Custom Post Types and its Taxonomies----- */

function vfic_pubs_forms_shortcode() { ?>
<div class="pub-search-form">

    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <p>Keyword(s): <input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="" id="s" class="s" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="abstract" value=""/>Just Search Abstract</p>

        <p>Author(s): &nbsp&nbsp <?php $myterms = get_terms(array('PubsAuthor'), array('order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>true));
                $author = "pubsauthors";
                $emptyvalue = "";
                $text = "text";
                    $term_taxonomy=$term->PubsAuthor; 
                    $term_slug=$term->slug;
                    $term_name =$term->name;
                    $link = $term_slug;
                    $output .="<input type='".$text."' name='".$link."'/>";

                echo $output; ?>
                    <?php $myterms = get_terms(array('PubsAuthor'), array('order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>true));
                $author = "pubsauthor";
                $emptyvalue = "";
                $output ="<select name='".$author."'><option selected='".$selected."' value='".$emptyvalue."'>--Select Authors--</option>'";

                foreach($myterms as $term){
                    $term_taxonomy=$term->PubsAuthor; 
                    $term_slug=$term->slug;
                    $term_name =$term->name;
                    $link = $term_slug;
                    $output .="<option name='".$link."' value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
                }
            $output .="</select>";
            echo $output;
                    ?></p>

       <p>Year:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <?php $myterms = get_terms(array('Year'), array('order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>true));
            $year = "pubsyear";
            $emptyvalue = "";
            $output ="<select name='".$year."'><option selected='".$selected."' value='".$emptyvalue."'>--Select Year--</option>'";

            foreach($myterms as $term){
                $term_taxonomy=$term->Year; 
                $term_slug=$term->slug;
                $term_name =$term->name;
                $link = $term_slug;
                $output .="<option name='".$link."' value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
            }
            $output .="</select>";
            echo $output;
        ?></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="vfic_publications" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>  
<?php } ?>
<?php add_shortcode('vfic_pubs_search', 'vfic_pubs_forms_shortcode');
add_filter( "template_redirect", "get_custom_post_type_template" ) ;?>
<?php function get_custom_post_type_template($template_redirect) {
         global $post;

         if ($post->post_type == 'vfic_publications') {
              $template_redirect = get_template_part('loop','vfic_publications');
         }
         return $template_redirect;
    } ?>
```

loop-{custom post type}.php page

```
get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $query_string;
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
$query_split = explode("=", $string);
$search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
$author = $_GET['pubsauthor'];
$abstract = $_GET['abstract'];

$tax_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
if ($_GET['pubsauthor'])
{
    $tax_query[] =  array(
            'taxonomy' => 'PubsAuthor',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($_GET['pubsauthor'])
        );
}
if ($_GET['pubsyear'])
{
    $tax_query[] =  array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Year',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($_GET['pubsyear'])
        );
}

$query = new WP_Query(
array(
    //Retreive ALL publications posts
    'post_type' => 'vfic_publications',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
)
);

?>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="content" role="main">
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <p><h2>Your search returned<?php /* Search Count */ $allsearch = &new      WP_Query(array(
    //Retreive ALL publications posts
    'post_type' => 'vfic_publications',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
    )); $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); $count = $allsearch->post_count;   _e(''); _e('<span class="search-terms">'); echo $key; _e('</span>'); _e(' &mdash; '); echo $count . ' '; _e('result(s)'); wp_reset_query(); ?></h2><br/>

<i>Please contact individual journals to obtain a full copy of the publication.</i><hr /><hr /></p>

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'agriflex' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><br/><hr />

<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>

<?php elseif ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="page-title">....<?php printf( __( 'Search %s', 'agriflex' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            <?php
            /* Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called loop-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
             get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' );
            ?>

<?php else : ?>
            <div id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'agriflex' ); ?></h2>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'agriflex' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #wrap -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help with this is really appreciated.

Comment: Never flush rewrite rules on init, you're massively slowing your site down

Comment: Also what page are you complaining about? Provide example URL of the page you're having an issue with

Comment: Also where's the source for single-vfic_publications.php ?

Comment: Also loop-{custom post type}.php is an invalid filename, { and } are not valid FS characters on most systems

Comment: The issue is with loop-{CPT}.php page. By loop-{custom post type} I meant the actual loop-vfic_publications.php page. There is no issue with the actual single-vfic_publications.php page. Sorry, the URL is currently on my localhost and not accessible outside firewall.

Comment: I don't want to go there myself, simply seeing the URL itself tells me important information

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename `loop-{custom-post-type}.php` to `single-{custom-post-type}.php`.

And to be explicit, the *actual* filename, based on your code above, should be:

**`single-vfic_publications.php`**.

Get rid of any other template redirects or anything else similar that you're using. As per the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), if you have a Custom Post Type named `vfic_publications`, and a template file named `single-vfic_publications.php`, WordPress will automatically use it to render the single-post view for that CPT.

The other issue that's going on here is that you appear to be trying to use the **single post view page** as an **archive index page**. You don't need to do that. Instead, create a **`archive-vfic_publications.php`** file, and WordPress will automatically use it to render the archive-index page view for your CPT.

You also appear to be doing tax queries in your template file. You might want to consider instead using [taxonomy template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code:

```
add_filter( "template_redirect", "get_custom_post_type_template" ) ;?>
<?php function get_custom_post_type_template($template_redirect) {
         global $post;

         if ($post->post_type == 'vfic_publications') {
              $template_redirect = get_template_part('loop','vfic_publications');
         }
         return $template_redirect;
    } ?>
```

But it's not clear why you would do such a thing. If you're trying to load loop-vfic_publications.php get_template_part won't work unless that file is in the theme.

If it is in the theme, then this function is a waste, and you should use the file `single-vfic_publications.php` instead with a `get_template_part()` to include the loop file.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_template_part` function is used to **include** a template file, not return the file path, which is expected.

I would change your line:

```
$template_redirect = get_template_part('loop','vfic_publications');
```

to

```
$templates = array( 'loop-vfic_publications.php', 'loop.php' );
$template_redirect = locate_template( $templates, false, false );
```